# SQL : Select the max of two occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i ve a little problem in sql, i can't reach a way to build the correct statement. i need to include in the result only the row having the maximum "sess" when "etud" and "mod" are equal in the occurrences :

```
etud|sess|mod|eta
1------1---M1--nv
1------2---M1--v
2------1---M1--nv
3------1---M1--v
4------1---M1--v
```

now the result i need is :

```
etud|sess|mod|eta
1------2---M1--v
2------1---M1--nv
3------1---M1--v
4------1---M1--v
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: How could `etud` and `mod` be equal?

Comment: @Lion I take that to mean eliminate the min sess per group of etud and mod.

Comment: Lion i believe you have misunderstood. The op means that only the row with the highest value for sess to be included if the resultset has multiple rows that share both etud and mod as a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a [`MAX()` aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max), grouping by `etud` and `mod`:

```
SELECT
  etud,
  MAX(sess) AS sess,
  mod
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY etud, mod
```

#### Update after edited quetsion:

Although MySQL will allow you to simply add the column to the query above without adding it to the `GROUP BY`, the value you get for that column is non-deterministic and if you have multiple possible values, you can't plan on which one you'll get back (usually it will be the first one though).

To pull in the remaining `eta` column matching the `MAX(sess)` you can join against a subquery.

```
SELECT
  main.etud,
  maxsess.maxsess AS sess
  main.mod,
  main.eta
FROM
  yourtable
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      etud,
      MAX(sess) AS maxsess,
      mod
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY etud, mod
    /* JOIN all 3 columns of the subquery which gets the MAX() against the rest of the table */
  ) maxsess ON main.etud = maxsess.etud AND main.sess = maxsess.maxsess AND main.mod = maxsess.mod
```

Comment: tnx a lot, as you see i'm still an SQL Beginner, what do you advise me to reach a nice skilled level ? :)

Comment: @TheEighthEro Write a lot of queries, and read a lot of questions tagged [sql] here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TheEighthEro And when you're ready to learn about SQL joins, read [this superb post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by Jeff Atwood (one of the creators of Stack Overflow)

Comment: the solution you 've just given doesn't work with the edited question, take a look at the edit . it returns for 1--2--M1-- ("nv") which is wrong , it must be 1--2--M1--v ;  Or ?

Comment: @TheEighthEro That is because MySQL is lenient about what columns you include in your output when they don't appear in the `GROUP BY`. Other RDBMS wouldn't allow what you attempted. See my edit above to pull in other columns  by joining against a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  etud,max(sess),  mod1
FROM tblA
GROUP BY etud, mod1
```

SQL FIDDLE [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dba65/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). I'm assuming you only want the max `sess` from each `etud-mod` paring which you can retrieve by this query:

```
SELECT etud, max(sess) as sess, mod FROM table GROUP BY etud, mod;
```

But in the off chance that you only want to remove the minimum `sess`, and get the other rows, then this is the one solution:

```
SELECT etud, sess, mod
FROM table 
JOIN (SELECT etud, min(sess) as sess, mod FROM table GROUP BY etud, mod) AS mintable
  ON table.etud = mintable.etud 
    AND table.mod = mintable.mod
    AND table.sess <> mintable.sess
```

As an example based on your question.

```
etud|sess|mod
1------1------M1
1------2------M1
1------3------M1
2------1------M1
2------2------M1
```

First query will return

```
etud|sess|mod
1------3------M1
2------2------M1
```

Second query will return

```
etud|sess|mod
1------2------M1
1------3------M1
2------2------M1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL table & inserts:
    create table esm (etud INT(11), sess INT(11), modval char(3))

```
INSERT INTO esm (etud,sess,modval) VALUES ( 1,1,'M1');
INSERT INTO esm (etud,sess,modval) VALUES ( 1,2,'M1');
INSERT INTO esm (etud,sess,modval) VALUES ( 2,1,'M1');
INSERT INTO esm (etud,sess,modval) VALUES ( 3,1,'M1');
INSERT INTO esm (etud,sess,modval) VALUES ( 4,1,'M1');
```

and the query:

```
SELECT esm1.* FROM esm esm1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(etud) as minetud, sess, modval
FROM  esm
GROUP BY   sess, modval) esm2
ON esm1.sess=esm2.sess AND esm1.modval=esm2.modval
WHERE esm1.etud <> minetud;
```

My results differ to the ones that you expect, but I think they reflect your statement of the problem.

```
+------+------+--------+
| etud | sess | modval |
+------+------+--------+
|    2 |    1 | M1     | 
|    3 |    1 | M1     | 
|    4 |    1 | M1     | 
+------+------+--------+
```